# Where to find info about WM Windows Message codes?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-messages

I see here and there pro users answer lots of noobs like me questions with things like `WM_PAINT = 0xf`  What should I search for to get complete list of this codes? are they all the same for all verions of windows? can they also used for other platforms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WM_PAINT = 0xf` is a specific parameter for a certain method. Those "codes" are usually needed with interop stuff, using unmanaged core libraries such as user32 and kernel32.

You can find methods and their parameters like that on the site [https://pinvoke.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20230923014257/https://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx).

For example, your example `WM_PAINT` is from [User32.GetMessage](https://web.archive.org/web/20230607050254/https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetMessage.html).

If you want a full list of specific [WindowsMessage](https://web.archive.org/web/20230923021218/https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html) parameters, they can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230620212929/http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html).

These days Microsoft has a project ["C#/Win32 P/Invoke Source Generator"](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) to interop with all the Win32 APIs. If you're trying to use Win32 APIs, that's probably the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: None of these links are working anymore.

Comment: Thank @Parrotmaster - I've updated the post with more recent information.

Answer (score 14):

Is [this table](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/WinMsgCodes.htm) of any help?

I'm not sure whether all Windows versions send all these message, but I'm pretty sure the codes aren't different between versions.

Answer (score 7):

You can find these in `WinUser.h`.

They cannot change between Windows versions (changing them would break binary compatibility with *all* Windows programs.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we also need a message by its code, decimal or hexadecimal. I find the following table useful:

https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation can be found on Microsoft's website in the section related to the use of the message.  Searching the ["Desktop" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/desktop-app-technologies) for the name of the message will usually give the correct page as the first result.  In almost all cases, that will include the numeric value.

Example with `WM_NCHITTEST` ([Search Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?scope=Desktop&terms=WM_NCHITTEST), [Doc Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest)):
[image: Example showing the define]

Personally, I use [magnumdb.com](https://www.magnumdb.com/) from which you can search either the constant in decimal or hex or the symbol (132 or 0x84 or `WM_NCHITTEST`).  MagnumDB is my first port-of-call for most any windows constant since it includes most everything to be imagined (Error codes, HResults, KnownFolderID, IIDs, CLSIDs, etc...).  [@SimonMourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) is the author of MagnumDB and is also quite active on StackOverflow.

[image: Example showing magnumdb used to search WM_NCHITTEST]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for it very long...

On the official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#system-defined-messages

On page "About Messages and Message Queues".
Paragraph: Message Types >> System-Defined Messages
A little further down there is a list with the lowest entry "WM General".